# using and displaying object data, PHP and json/jquery

Tags: php, oop

I am running into a brick wall when passing object data from jquery to PHP.  I'm still trying to get my head around OOP.

Code follows:

```
        <script type ="text/javascript">
      $(function() { 


    $(".button").click(function() {
          //alert("click");


          var jsonvar1 = {"skillz": {
                            "web":[
                                    {"name": "html", 
                                     "years": "5"
                                    },
                                    {"name": "css", 
                                     "years": "3"
                                    }],
                            "database":[
                                    {"name": "sql", 
                                     "years": "7"
                                    }]
        }};



          $.ajax({
            url: "test2.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'regemail=' + jsonvar1,



                success: function(result) {
                alert(result);

                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
            });

      });
      });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

<input type="button" id="regSubmit" class="button" value="Register!" /></br></span>
<script>
$('input[type=button]').attr('disabled', false);
    //alert('test');
</script>
```

The above code does 3 things.  Catches a button click, and then: eclares a variable (jsonvar1), and performs an ajax request on that variable to a PHP backend.

Now the code in the PHP backend:

```
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "regemail")) {

    $data = $_REQUEST["regemail"];

    //echo "<br>I got some data!</br>";

    //print_r($data);

    //echo $data->skillz;

    //echo $data;

    var_dump($data);

} else {

echo "No Data.";
}
```

(safely ignore all the echoes and dumps in the above PHP. That would be me flailing about trying to use the data in some fashion)

**Question:  How can I pull data from the object in PHP into variables or an array, or if you prefer, how can I work directly with the values in that object?**  (assuming it is an object, and that I'm not making some other unrelated mistake)

I'm wondering if I've neglected to tell my request that it is JSON...  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Edit:

I've attempted to add
    echo json_decode($data);
to my PHP code, but it returns a blank dataset.

I also attempted to put
    dataType: 'json',
in my ajax query.

Still not having any luck it seems.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

Comment: have you looked into the PHP json functions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)?  I might be wrong but I think json_decode is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) for that on the server side.

```
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "regemail")) {
    $data = $_REQUEST["regemail"];

    //echo "<br>I got some data!</br>";
    //print_r($data);
    //echo $data->skillz;

    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo "No Data.";
}
```

Comment: hm,  this returns [object Object]

Comment: I noticed you accepted my answer but your comment suggests a problem. Did you encounter something else?

Answer (score 1):

You have run into a rather simple error which is easy to overlook: jsonvar1 contains an object, and when you concatenate it to "regemail=" with the + operator, it is turned into a string - but not in the way you intended. The resulting string is "[object Object]" because JSON conversion is not done automatically for you. Instead, the line should be

```
data: 'regemail=' + JSON.stringify(jsonvar1),
```

In your PHP file, the line

```
$data = json_decode( $data );
```

will give you an object to work with, as @sirlancelot has already said.